# Using bitwise operations in if statement

Tags: c#, bit

Can someone explain why is this not valid? I get "can't convert to int to bool"

```
 if (b & 1)
```

also, why can't I do

```
 b & 1
```

in code, is this the correct way of doing this?

```
 int b = b & 1
 if(b)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because the result of b & 1 is an integer (if b is an integer).

A correct way to do this is (among others):

```
if ((b & 1) != 0) { ... }
```

or

`if (Convert.ToBoolean(b & 1)) { ... }`

Comment: Note that your third example will also fail for this reason.  You'd have to convert "b" to an integer or compare it with 0, since `if` can only compare boolean expressions.

Comment: so if I want to do a regular bit operation like this somewhere in the code (b&8) like I would in javascript, c# I would have to write b = b & 2; correct?

Comment: No, you don't need to store the result in a variable (seem my first example); you just need to understand that the result will be strongly-typed as an integer, and that you will have to convert it or compare it to another integer.  Note that C# doesn't consider 0 to be "false" like C or JS does.  In my first example, I'm literally comparing the integer output of b & 1 to the number 0.

Comment: when if(b & 1) gets executed, does the b value get updated and will differ after if stamement or it works the same way as if(a-1>3) where a stays the same after the if statement, not like a = a -1; if that makes sense

Comment: In both of your examples, both "a" and "b" never change.  As I said, just the expression `if (b & 1)` is illegal, since `b & 1` is not a boolean expression, so your question doesn't really make any sense... The expression `if(b & 1)` is equivalent to `c = b & 1; if (c)`.